# What's "rouleaux" in this sentence?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

What is the meaning of *"les rouleaux"* in the following sentence : « Avant d'aller travailler, ce diplômé d'école de commerce se rafraîchit les idées dans les rouleaux. »

Comment: We don't do translations here, but we can definitely help you with the meaning of the sentence. However this is not a common French idiom. I don't know what it means. It might make sense in context though. So tell us where you found this. Give us more surrounding sentences if possible.

Comment: @Gilles: OP's not asking for translation of complete sentence but just on meaning of one word. Rephrasing the question might do?

Comment: Un [rouleau](http://www.easyvoyage.com/images/attractions/5800/570x360/8647.jpg) est une grande vague déferlante appelée ainsi à cause de sa forme en forme de rouleau. Rouleau a de très nombreux sens, mais ici c'est le contexte qui nous aide à comprendre : pour se **rafraîchir les idées** il va faire un plongeon dans l'océan, ou du surf (les rouleaux sont les [vagues préférées des sufers](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2010_mavericks_competition_edit1.jpg)).

Comment: Faut avouer que, sans contexte, pas évident de penser au surf.

Answer (score 4):

Le mot rouleau a de nombreux sens, et ici le contexte nous aide à comprendre. 
Un [rouleau](http://www.easyvoyage.com/images/attractions/5800/570x360/8647.jpg) est une grande vague déferlante appelée ainsi à cause de sa forme. Pour se **rafraîchir**  il va dans l'océan, soit juste plonger ou nager, soit faire du surf :  les rouleaux sont les [vagues préférées des surfers](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2010_mavericks_competition_edit1.jpg) !